# R: Plotting "Actual vs. Fitted"

Tags: r, plot, regression, model-fitting

I do have a question related to plotting actual data of a time series and the values from a fitted model. In particular, my questions relate to this paper:

https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//googleblogs/pdfs/google_predicting_the_present.pdf

In the appendix of the document, you can find an R script. Here, I do have two initial questions: (1) What does

```
##### Define Predictors - Time Lags;
dat$s1 = c(NA, dat$sales[1:(nrow(dat)-1)]);
dat$s12 = c(rep(NA, 12), dat$sales[1:(nrow(dat)-12)]);
```

do and what is the function of:

```
##### Divide data by two parts - model fitting & prediction
dat1 = mdat[1:(nrow(mdat)-1), ]
dat2 = mdat[nrow(mdat), ]
```

Final and main question: Let's say I get a calculation for my data with

```
fit = lm(log(sales) ~ log(s1) + log(s12) + trends1, data=dat1);
summary(fit)
```

The adj. R-squared value is 0.342. Thus, I'd argue that the model above explains roughly 34% of the variance between modeled data (predictive data?) and the actual data. Now, how can I plot this "model graph" (fitted) so that I get something like this in the paper?

[image: Fitted]

I assume the second graph's "fitted" is actually the data from the estimated model, right? If so, then this part seems missing in the script.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 1:**

Tried this:

```
# Actual values and fitted values
plot(sales ~ month, data= dat1, col="blue", lwd=1, type="l", xaxt = "n", xaxs="r",yaxs="r", xlab="", ylab="Total Sales");
par(new=TRUE)
plot(fitted(fit) ~ month, data= dat1, col="red", lwd=1, type="l", xaxs="r", yaxs="r", yaxt = "n", xlab="Month", ylab="Index", xaxt="n");
axis(4)
```

Output: Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : variable lengths differ (found for 'month')

Answer (score 1):

```
dat$s1 = c(NA, dat$sales[1:(nrow(dat)-1)])
```

This creates a new column `s1` with data from `sales` where first element is NA. Last item from `sales` is missing.

```
dat$s12 = c(rep(NA, 12), dat$sales[1:(nrow(dat)-12)])
```

Crate `s12` column with 12 NAs and the rest is first `nrow(dat)-12` values from `dat$sales`.

```
dat1 = mdat[1:(nrow(mdat)-1), ]
dat2 = mdat[nrow(mdat), ]
```

`dat1` is all but last observation (rows), `dat2` is only last row. When predicting the response (`sales`), you only need to feed a data.frame with at least the columns that are on the right side of the formula (called also explanatory variables), in this case `s1` and `s12`, as a `newdata` argument to `predict()` function. This is where `dat2` is used.

```
predict.fit = predict(fit, newdata=dat2, se.fit=TRUE)
```

This next line fits a model using `dat1`.

```
fit = lm(log(sales) ~ log(s1) + log(s12) + trends1, data=dat1)
```

`fitted(fit)` will give you fitted values. Try `predict(fit)` and compare if it's any different.

Semicolons at the end of each statement is redundant.

Comment: I tried something in Edit 1. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. But I can see the values through fitted(fit).

Comment: Could you help me with the meaning of "##### Divide data by two parts - model fitting & prediction
dat1 = mdat[1:(nrow(mdat)-1), ]
dat2 = mdat[nrow(mdat), ]"? I do not understand the sense of dat2.